# Check if file with pattern exist

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, path, wildcard

I have a strange situation and I don't know what is wrong

I need to check if in a directory exist at least one file with a pattern.

```
IF EXIST d:\*Backup*.* (
   ECHO "file exist"
) ELSE (
   ECHO "file not exist"
)
```

If on `d:\` I have a file `x_Backup.txt` and a folder `Backup` I get `file exist` but if i have only folder `Backup` I get again `file exist`, seems that the dot from path is ignored.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are undocumented wildcards that you can use to achieve this as well.

```
IF EXIST "D:\*Backup*.<" (
   ECHO "file exist"
) ELSE (
   ECHO "file not exist"
)
```

This wildcard option and other were discussed in length at the following two links.
http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6207

http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5057

From those links:

```
The following wildcard characters can be used in the pattern string.

Wildcard character  Meaning

* (asterisk)
Matches zero or more characters

? (question mark)
Matches a single character

" 
Matches either a period or zero characters beyond the name string

>
Matches any single character or, upon encountering a period or end of name string, advances the expression to the end of the set of contiguous >

<
Matches zero or more characters until encountering and matching the final . in the name
```

Comment: plus-one! Although you should include a link to the description of the undocumented wildcards...

Comment: on windows 10 this return allways "file not exist". On which version of windows work? Because is undocumented, I cannot use on a productive project

Comment: @vasilenicusor, there were changes to CMD.exe probably for the first time in a long time when Windows 10 came out.  I can't test on Windows 10.  Works on Windows 7 for sure.  Pretty sure on XP as well.  I will post two links to DosTips.com where we discussed this subject at length.

Comment: @Squashman Thanks. For the moment, the best solution for me is to call `dir /b d:\ > myfile.txt` and then check if regex match on myfile.txt with `findstr` command

Comment: @vasilenicusor, why would you use dir and pipe to the FINDSTR command.  The code that Aacini gave you works just fine.

Comment: @Squashman I know but somebody told me that is not safe. I prefer FINDSTR because regex

Comment: @vasilenicusor, please invite them to discuss that theory over here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97555/discussion-between-squashman-and-vasilenicusor).

Comment: After checking my test script, i found a mistake in the drive letter used. now works fine. +1 @Squashman

Answer (score 6):

Use this; it works with any specific pattern:

```
set "fileExist="
for %%a in (d:\*Backup*.*) do set "fileExist=1" & goto continue
:continue
IF DEFINED fileExist (
   ECHO "file exist"
) ELSE (
   ECHO "file not exist"
)
```

Comment: Was trying to use the undocumented wildcards that we discussed over on DosTips but could not get them to work.  Did you try them at all?

Comment: I figured it out. `IF EXIST "H:\*Backup*.<" echo exists`

Comment: In some cases similar For method would be a win/win - because we could actually look inside folders with something like "dir \s *.txt"

Answer (score 5):

This is another alternative.

```
dir d:\*back*.* /b /a-d >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 echo files exist
```

Comment: even cleaner then using 'for' methond. Thanks!
I'm going to look in subdirs with something like
"dir %RootDirPath%\\*.xml /s /b /a-d >nul 2>&"

Answer (score 2):

`*.*` is equivalent to `*` in dos. It just means 'anything', not anything-period-anything.

To check for the directory, try this:

```
IF EXIST D:\*Backup*\ (
   ECHO "directory exist"
) ELSE (
   ECHO "directory not exist"
)
```

Comment: i need to check if exist only files with this pattern