# gitlab runner catch error: no matching files

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Is there a a way to catch a error if there are no matching files found or a batch file gave a error like this?

```
...
Rebuild complete.
Syntaxerror.
Syntaxerror.
Syntaxerror.
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: Ticket/Ticket_111b: no matching files     
WARNING: Failed to load system CertPool: crypto/x509: system root pool is not available on Windows 
Uploading artifacts to coordinator... ok            id=622 responseStatus=201 Created token=xxxxxx
Job succeeded
```

Result shows job was executed successly. how can gitlab-runner know the error in the batch file or the no matching files-warning?

gitlab YAML file:

```
before_script:
  - xcopy /y /s "C:/Bauen" "%CI_PROJECT_DIR%"


stages:
  - build
  - deploy





build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - build.cmd
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    name: "%CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME%"
    paths:
      - "%CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME%"
  only:
  - tags
  except:
  - master


build_master:
  stage: build
  script:
  - buildm.cmd
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    name: "%CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME%"
    paths:
      - "%CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME%"
  only:
  - master

deploy:
 stage: deploy
 script:
 - ./upload.cmd
 dependencies:
 - build_master
 only:
 - master
```

The GitLab Runner runs on a windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to perfectly understand what you want.

Do you want to stop the job if some files are not present?

If so you just have to add a line in the script section that fails if your files don't exist. For instance, in bash:

```
script:
- ls this_file_must_exists
```

Comment: your answer does not help, sorry

Comment: So could you clarify your needs?

Comment: The pipeline should stop as soon as an alert is issued as above. Currently he declares that the pipeline is successful, which of course is wrong.

Comment: The job failure/succes can not be linked to the artifacts. The only way is to check yourself the condition and then fail the job if needed.

Comment: okay, but ls is linux only. dir does not fail the job if data not found

Comment: I am not an expert of the dark side but I am pretty sure an equivalent exists: [Batch-file: Check if file with pattern exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34206104/2182582)