# *.* as pattern for folders and files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wildcard

In batch file scripts and the doc pages (e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr)) I often see `*.*` as (I guess) a way to specify multiple folder/ file names. My question is: How exactly this string `*.*` is interpreted by `cmd.exe`?

I know that specify folder/ file names two special characters can be used:

1. `*` means any number of character (including zero)
2. `?` one character

So `*.txt` would mean all files with extension `.txt` in the current directory. In light of this, I would read `*.*` as any folder/file name that has `.` (dot) in it.

Why then when I run `DIR *.*` in a folder that has only a subfolder named `folder` and a file named `script.txt`, it displays `folder` and `script.txt` instead of just showing `script.txt`?

Comment: `cmd.exe` does not interpret `*.*` or any other wildcard pattern at all. It passes the string to the appropriate Windows file API function. I recommend to read the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) and [FindFirstFileW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilew) and [FindNextFileW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilew).

Comment: Take a look at this Super User thread: [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874) (regarding just the source mask for the `dir` command, for instance) Most internal commands and many external ones behave like that…

Comment: Is `?` not generally `0` or `1` character? With `where.exe`, it is `1` character only, but I'm unaware of another utility which has that ’quirk’.

Comment: @aschipfl if I read the thread correctly, it means that `*.*` can also match e.g. a name `aaa` because `.*` in `*.*` can match nothing. Scary to read at the beginning of the thread "These rules were discovered after extensive TESTING..."

Comment: If I wanted to use `Dir` to list files and/or directories, I'd just use `Dir` with no glob at all! (At the very least simply `Dir *` should suffice.)

Comment: @Compo I would do the same, but I am still curious about the logic behind `*.*`.

Comment: These masks come from ages where file names consisted of an 8-character base name and a 3-character extension, the so-called 8.3 file names; with that in mind, the wildcards may make more sense. Anyway, `*.*` and `*` are usually equivalent, with `.*` meaning every extension, even a blank one. `?` usually means one character, except at the end, it may also mean none (e. g., `???` matches file names with up to 3 characters). However, some commands (like `where` or `forfiles`) have got their own wildcard parsing rules, which makes the whole thing quite complicated…

Comment: Not enough, there are even undocumented wildcards, namely `<` (similar to `*`) and `>` (similar to `?`) – see also [Check if file with pattern exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34206104) and [FindFirstFile undocumented wildcard or bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24193649) for more information about them…

Comment: Also refer to this Super User thread concerning wildcards: [Why does `dir *.*` give me all files and folders?](https://superuser.com/q/1193102)

Comment: files in Win32 namespace always contain a hidden dot at the end, so `*.*` always match all files, unless you use PowerShell